# Is there any tool that can be used to design the Oracle development

Tags: oracle12c

I am working as SQL developer and I frequently need to work or several table joining and creation which have multiple dependence.
I need to have a handy tool that can help to to first design the each step and development approach then start it's development.

Can someone help me to find such tool?

Answer (score 1):

As you already use SQL Developer, why wouldn't you also use [SQL Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html)?

> Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler is a free graphical tool that
>   enhances productivity and simplifies data modeling tasks. Using Oracle
>   SQL Developer Data Modeler users can create, browse and edit, logical,
>   relational, physical, multi-dimensional, and data type models. (...)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to use SQL developer data modeler.. I have installed it and struggling to properly use it .... Do I need to import the complete schema structure into the modeler?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know; I don't use that tool.